# Time evolution of generalized angular momentum operator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, angular-momentum, conservation-laws

We define this operator : 
$$M^{\mu\nu} = \int d^3x~(x^{\mu}T^{0\nu} - x^{\nu}T^{0\mu})$$ where $T_{\mu\nu}$ is the energy momentum tensor (see e.g. [Energy momentum tensor from Noether's theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19297/energy-momentum-tensor-from-noethers-theorem)) for a scalar field. Concentrate on the boost operator $M^{0i}$ (where $x^0$ appears explicitly). We can easily prove that its derivative with respect to $x^0$ is zero using integration by parts and the local conservation of $T_{\mu\nu}$. Now using the Heisenberg picture, we can take this operator and evolute it with $$U=e^{-iHt}$$ and $U^\dagger$. Taking $t$ small, you develop, keep first order in t and get (where the term in the parenthesis goes for $x^0$)
$$M^{\mu\nu}(t) = M^{\mu\nu}(0)  + it[H,M^{\mu\nu}(0)].$$
But, $M^{\mu\nu}$ is a generator of the [Poincaré group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_group) and its commutation relations must satisfy in particular : 
$$[M^{0i},H]=iP^i$$ (it's not zero and serves to make the good translation in the first term of $M^{0i}$). Where is the blunder ? On one side, you have a conservation law, on the other, a consistent evolution.

Answer (score 2):

The quantum version of Noether's theorem are the [Ward-Takahashi identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward%E2%80%93Takahashi_identity).

Classical conservation laws only hold "inside expectation values", so you should not expect a classically conserved operator to have no time evolution quantumly.

Additionally, switching to the Hamiltonian formalism *breaks* manifest Lorentz invariance, so you should also not expect anything to behave in an evidently covariant way here - the final S-matrix elements/expectation values will be Poincare invariant, but steps on the way may well look as if they violate Poincare symmetry/some conservation law derived from it.