Confusion about Noether's Theorem
In classical mechanics, a transformation $q \rightarrow q + \delta q$ is a symmetry if the resultant change in the Lagrangian is a total derivative,
$$ \delta L = \frac{dF}{dt}.$$
If we derive the change in the Lagrangian corresponding to an arbitrary transformation, we get
\begin{align}
\delta L &= \frac{\partial L}{\partial q} \delta q + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} \frac{d\delta q}{dt} \tag{2.1}
\end{align}
Observe that
\begin{equation}
    \frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} \delta q \right) = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} \delta q + \frac{\partial L
    }{\partial \dot{q}} \frac{d \delta q}{dt} \tag{2.2}
\end{equation}
Assuming we are on a solution trajectory, we may use the Euler-Lagrange equation, which states that
\begin{equation}
    \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L }{\partial \dot{q}} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial q} \tag{2.3}
\end{equation}
Solving for the second term on the RHS of (2.2) and substituting the result of (2.3), we have
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial L
    }{\partial \dot{q}} \frac{d \delta q}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} \delta q \right) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial q} \delta q \tag{2.4}
\end{equation}
Finally, putting this back into (2.1), we obtain
\begin{equation}
    \delta L = \frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} \delta q \right) \tag{2.5}
\end{equation}
Which states that {any} transformation about a solution trajectory is a symmetry because the induced change in the Lagrangian is a total derivative.
My question, now, is very simple: Obviously not all transformations are symmetries unlike my derivation above shows, so what went wrong?
Edit: Traditionally, we would end the argument by equating (2.5) to $\frac{dF}{dt}$ and then by calling $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} \delta q - F$ the conserved quantity. The problem I see with this is: why do we look for another function $F$ such that $\delta L = \frac{dF}{dt}$ is satisfied when $\delta L$ is already a total time derivative.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/438403/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/438351/2451

Let us start from $$\delta L= \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial q}\delta q+\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}\delta\dot q.$$
We can use the product rule for derivatives to rewrite
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}\delta q\right) = \dfrac{d}{dt}\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}\delta q+\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}\delta \dot q.$$
This means that $\delta L$ for a generic variation, takes the form $$\delta L = E\delta q+\dfrac{d\Theta}{dt},\quad E\equiv \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial q}-\dfrac{d}{dt}\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q},\quad \Theta \equiv \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}\delta q.$$
The quantity $E$ determines the equation of motion $E = 0$, while $\Theta$ is an object called pre-symplectic potential. In fact, if we define the canonical momentum $$p \equiv \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}$$
then $\Theta = p\delta q$. The observation now is that given the action $S$ we observe that the contribution to $\delta S$ from $\Theta$ is a boundary term. More precisely, if the path is defined on the interval $[a,b]$ the contribution is gives $p(b)\delta q(b)-p(a)\delta q(a)$. If we are considering variations keeping endpoints fixed, $\delta q(a)=\delta q(b)=0$ and therefore this contribution drops out.
As a result, demanding $\delta S=0$ for all variations keeping endpoints fixed yields $E=0$ because the $\Theta$ term doesn't contribute. If you then pick a path that solves the equations of motion, i.e., that has $E=0$, obviously you will get $\delta L = \frac{d\Theta}{dt}$, a total derivative, but that doesn't say the variation is a symmetry, because it relied on using a path that solves the equations of motion.
A (quasi)-symmetry is a variation that applied to any path (solving EOM or not), yields $\delta L = \frac{dK}{dt}$. The reason is that in this case $$\dfrac{dK}{dt} = E\delta q + \dfrac{d\Theta}{dt} \Longrightarrow \dfrac{d(K-\Theta)}{dt} = E\delta q,$$
and when restricted to a classical solution, $E=0$ and therefore $P=K-\Theta$ is conserved.
In fact, a symmetry is the special case $K=0$ where $\delta L=0$ and the Lagrangian is preserved. The whole motivation to define a quasi-symmetry like that is exactly that it is a minor modification to Noether's theorem that allows for a conserved charge also.
By the way, a nice by-product of this kind of analysis is the appearance of $\Theta$. When you study Hamiltonian mechanics you will learn that there is an object called symplectic form, which is   the exterior derivative of $\Theta$, namely, $\Omega = \delta p\wedge \delta q$. This is going to be a two-form in phase space that determines the Poisson bracket. What this analysis shows is that the symplectic potential - and hence the symplectic form - can be read off from varying the Lagrangian and writing it in the form as we did here.

It is not enough that the transformation leaves the Lagrangian unchanged for solutions of the equation of motion. To be a symmetry, the Lagrangian should be unchanged (up to a total time derivative) for any trajectory, solution or not.
Notice that when the Euler-Lagrange equations are derived from the principle of stationary action, the requirement of for a solution $q(t)$ is that precisely that it leaves the action unchanged for infinitesimal variations $q \rightarrow q + \delta q$. In other words that
$$\delta S = \int d t \delta L(q, \dot{q}, t) = 0,$$
What you've shown is just the same, but in reverse - that trajectories that satisfy the Euler-Lagrange equation are stationary points of the action.

ok, the change should be a total derivative for all trajectories, makes a lot of sense. However, in all derivations about Noether's theorem and converved currents and what not, the EL equations are always invoked, meaning we're always considering transformations about a solution trajectory.

In the end, one is probably interested in solution trajectories - but you can't take such a trajectory as a starting point if you want to show that a transformation is a symmetry
